# How do I Count up in a url while capturing source code

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop though a number of url requests but I'm having an issue, when I run the code it doesnt loop though all the numbers and only requests the page once with the output.

So my question is, how do I loop though the numbers in the url while requesting each one + capturing all the source code I need. Everything works except the counting.

this is the code I have managed to write so far

```
import urllib.request
import re
count = 1
while count <= 44:
    url = ('https://example/page=%i' % count)
    count += 1
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
paragraphs = re.findall(r';"><span>(.*?)</span></a></td><td',str(respData))
for eachP in paragraphs:
    print(eachP)
```

Comment: You're first looping through the entire while loop, then requesting the url at which point the url is for 44. That runs once. And then it's the end of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in your loop you iterate over all 44 urls, but request only last one url, this is correct implementation:

```
import urllib.request
import re


def handle_url(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    paragraphs = re.findall(r';"><span>(.*?)</span></a></td><td',str(respData))
    for eachP in paragraphs:
        print(eachP)


count = 1
while count <= 44:
    handle_url('https://example/page=%i' % count)
    count += 1
```

if you don't like function you can simply move all to while loop:

```
import urllib.request
import re


def handle_url(url):



count = 1
while count <= 44:
    url = 'https://example/page=%i' % count
    count += 1
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    paragraphs = re.findall(r';"><span>(.*?)</span></a></td><td',str(respData))
    for eachP in paragraphs:
        print(eachP)
```